# A music widget that works with Google Music streaming and offline service?

Tags: music, app-widgets, google-play-music

I'd like a widget to display playing info and cover art that works with latest Google Music app, more importantly both while playing offline tracks (those marked to be offline, so actually Google Music cached tracks) and also streaming ones.
Do you know any?
Thanks.

Comment: There are a few different apps on the market that claim to be able provide a widget that can control Google music (Pure Music was one, but a paid app).  However it is unclear which app they mean when they say "Stock Music App"  Some phones are going to have the pre-cloud version of the music player as stock.  (The pre-cloud widget supports cover art)

As there is no API for Google Play Music, it may not be possible for 3rd party widgets to do this.  Though Google has said that the #1 user requests was more/better widgets for the music app, so perhaps there will be better options soon.

Comment: So it's an API issue, then. Too bad, Google really has to get going with APIs (G+ is like embarassing).
Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go check "Plug in music widget" at Android Market. It's working with Google Music and free.

Comment: Could you please add a link to the widget?

Comment: Wow, this is really good! https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.seya.plugmusic&hl=en